# Badges have become light in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode

Sometime in the last hour or so the badges in the activity tab of the profile* have changed:
[image: screenshot with light-grey-text-on-white badges in dark theme]

On hover the badges are dark again.

(*For the record, it's also visible in dupe closure banners and https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges, but these have to be the same style.)

Comment: In addition to the primary.css rule of `.badge:hover, .badge-tag:hover { color: hsl(0,0%,100%); background-color: hsl(210,8%,5%);}` not taking into account dark mode, there's also an issue with the `:hover` classes, which use `.badge:hover, .badge-tag:hover {color: hsl(0,0%,100%); background-color: hsl(210,8%,5%);}` It looks like the CSS handles dark mode in two different ways A) by using CSS variables to change what the colors are and B) use explicit `body.theme-dark` rules. It would be better if the CSS consistently used the color value variables, so that dark mode and theming was handled.

Comment: Potentially related: [High contrast mode beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411820)

Comment: Plot twist:  It's become a spoiler-like bait so you have to hover/click to see what badge you got.

Comment: @Ollie You have to see all of the user's posts in order to know that, if you don't want the spoilers :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! This is related to the [High contrast mode beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411820) mentioned by @VLAZ. We have a fix in the works!

Comment: Catching it was easy, but I first had to regain my vision to report it! :P Thanks, fix is live now.